# External RSS feed to Wordpress Portfolio

Tags: plugins, php, posts, rss

I am new to this RSS feed integration to WordPress site. I need some help in Integration part, I have a RSS feed, where I can feed the data and store in a class, and I can create a new Portfolio to meet that requirement, But I cant able to import and save them in Wordpress Portfolio.. Like for example. Custom post type Vehicles_ID wordpress to Vehicles_ID in RSS feed. Please need help..